# Condición para no mostrar componentes en Angular o HTML

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive, angular-directivas

Estoy diseñando una webapp y codificando 2 vistas. Para tablet y mobile.
En cada caso hay componentes que no están en la otra y viceversa.

Por ejemplo:

- Tengo una etiqueta `<p>`: `<p class="saludo">¡Hola {{user.name}}!, buenos días</p>`

En el caso de mobile no quiero que se muestre, pero para tablet si quiero.

Lo que hice fue:

```
//Tablet 1024px
@media screen and (min-width: 441px) and (max-width: 1024) {
.saludo{
        //Estilos correspondientes
    }
}

//Mobile 440px
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 440px) {
.saludo{
        display: none;
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Esto no me parece del todo correcto (quisiera saber si está bien visto o no) porque al inspeccionar la página y ver los elementos. La etiqueta `<p>` para mobile existe.

Estuve buscando y no encontré nada al respecto.
Pero mi consulta era si existe alguna función u opción de Angular para tomar las medidas de la ventana desde el html para usar con la directiva `ngIf`. Por ejemplo:

```
<p class="saludo" *ngIf="window.widht > 440px">¡Hola {{user.name}}!, buenos días</p>
```

El objetivo es no crear ninguna función para obtener el tamaño de la ventana.

Comment: ¿Si está bien visto? Sí, así funciona el diseño adaptativo.  Usar `*ngIf` es más usado para ocultar/mostrar elementos si eso depende de eventos o condiciones  en la aplicación.

Comment: Genial!! No encontraba en ningún lado si estaba bien o mal. Muchisimas gracias!

Comment: No conozco angular, pero en vanilla window.innerwidth te devuelve el ancho del viewport. Imagino como en react podras llamar a funciones del objeto window desde dentro de los componentes

Comment: Esto te puede ayudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034573/ngif-hide-some-content-on-mobile-screen-angular-4

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el [layout](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview) de la `cdk` de **angular material** con la directiva `ngIf` y [ng-container](https://angular.io/api/core/ng-container).

```
@Component({...})
class MyComponent {
 constructor(mediaMatcher: MediaMatcher) {
  const mediaQueryList = mediaMatcher.matchMedia('(min-width: 1px)');
 }
}
```